# Can't use setMyLocationButtonEnabled Android Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation

I was trying to add the button, My Location, to show the user localization but it doesn't shows up, I have added permission in the manifest file and add setMyLocationButtonEnabled on java why doesn't it work?

```
   @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        LatLng coordenadas = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordenadas, 6));

        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        UiSettings uiSettings = googleMap.getUiSettings();
        uiSettings.setAllGesturesEnabled(true);
        uiSettings.setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        uiSettings.setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        uiSettings.setIndoorLevelPickerEnabled(true);
    }
```

Comment: Are you tagetting, API level 23? If yes you have to define `runtime permission`

Comment: did u call `mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);`?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/UiSettings.html#setMyLocationButtonEnabled(boolean)) (emphasys mine):

> Enables or disables the my-location button. The my-location button causes the camera to move such that the user's location is in the center of the map. **If the button is enabled, it is only shown when the my-location layer is enabled.**

So you need to enable the *my location layer* doing:

```
googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
```

if you target  API level 23

You have to add RealTime permission

Like This

```
if(!checkLocationPermission(this))
        {
            Log.e("checkLocationPermission","NO premisstion");

            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                Log.e("checkLocationPermission","Should");

                // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

            } else {
                Log.e("checkLocationPermission"," NOT Should");

                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

                // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
                // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
                // result of the request.
            }
        }
```

and checkLocationPermission Function

```
  public static boolean checkLocationPermission(Context context) {
        return ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission
                (context, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) !=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }
```

where MY_PERMISSIONS_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION  is int 
Id of request

Comment: welp, please :)

Comment: I dont understand , More explain Please

Comment: On the else  ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSIONS_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION); Error: Cannot resolve symbol MY_PERMISSIONS_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

Comment: oohhh    iam so sorry  , i forget
    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 102;

it`s request ID so you can receive the result in (OnActivityresult)